# Why can't I do heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I finished the first heist on GTA online. I started the second heist the prison break. Me and other players finished the setup for it and the wet works unlocked I tried starting it as host but it says it will mess up my all in order challenge. I tried like 5 times and even quit the game left my apartment and turned off the system but it still says this. Do you know what's going on? Also, right now I could play the heist as a team member not host without messing the all in order challenge.

Comment: BTW that is also my ps3 gamer tag Dark_Thunder_2

Comment: Did you start the first mission(host)? If not, that's why.

Comment: Wasn't heists Ps4, XB1 and PC(whenever that comes out) only? I thought I recall reading that somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you start a heist as host, then you have to do *all* heist missions, including all setups. You cannot skip any of the missions when starting a heist as a host. In your case, this will mean not doing the heist missions in order.

Answer (score 1):

Check this site for requirements: [iDigitalTimes heist overview](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/gta-v-online-heist-requirement-checklist-heres-everything-you-need-do-heists-421163). Hopefully it has your solution. I'm copying the first part of it below.

> #### Quick Checklist
>
> If you just want the quick run-down of what you need to do, here you go. I'll explain each step further below if you are confused.
>
> - Heist Leader must be level 12 or higher
> - Heist Leader must own a high-end apartment with a planning board
> - Heist Leader must have enough money to front the cost of the heist him/herself**
>
> ...

Comment: Please summarize the information from the link in your answer.  That way, if the site ever goes down (which seems rather probable), your answer is still valid.

Comment: You should probably add the relevant information from the link in your answer in case the link goes down. As it stands, if that were to happen, your answer would be rendered just about useless.

Comment: Very much appreciated.